# Migrate users data from django to drupal 7

Tags: django, drupal-7

Is there a way to migrate users data from django to drupal-7. I have 800 users in my old django website and want to migrate these users to drupal-7. Please suggest some tricks or tutorial. I googled a lot but was unable to find any direct solution.

Thank you for your help and suggestions.

Comment: I doubt there is some ready tool for this. You can easily make a django command to read from django's users table and write to the drupal db.

Comment: I suggest you to learn and desribe here what data is stored for each user in each django and drupal. If you do so, you will be able to create a custom solution to migrate stuff the is important.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is not an module for this, specifically. But the [migrate module](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate) can help you with the migration. It demands that you create some code for the migration. But it is necessary only if your users have a lot of custom fields.

If they are simple users (username/email/password), you only would need to make a simple script to create users. In that case, you can use the [drupal_bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/node/1436272) to start it from an external script and with [user_save](http://codekarate.com/blog/create-user-account-drupal-7-programmatically) create the users.

```
<?php
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', '/path/to/drupal');
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_boostrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

//set up the user fields
$fields = array(
   'name' => 'user_name',
   'mail' => 'user_name@example.com',
   'pass' => $password,
   'status' => 1,
   'init' => 'email address',
   'roles' => array(
     DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID => 'authenticated user',
   ),
);

//the first parameter is left blank so a new user is created
$account = user_save('', $fields);
```